# A better approach to encrypt and transfer a file

Tags: java, sockets

To transfer a file over socket I'd first try and generate a **hash** for the original file, then I try to transfer to my mock server and after the server has received the file it will also generate a **hash** and then compare both to see if the file has not been corrupted during the transfer.

Now I am trying to transfer a file I need to encrypt, from my android phone to my mock server, I thought of doing this

```
while(..reading file from stream){
//encrypt read bytes
//write read bytes to socket
}
```

D problem is I am unsure of how to generate a hash for it that way.
Or will this be a better approach:

```
While(reading normal fileA..){
//encrypt read bytes
//write d encrypted bytes  in another fileB
}
//after done
//generate a hash from FileB
```

Then I can send the encrypted file and hash to server and generate a hash and compare

What if  fileA is 1gb in Size, if I choose option 2 I'd need to generate another 1gb of d encrypted fileB and that's consuming space!

Which would b a better approach? Thanks in advance

Comment: you can generate hash during encryption and send it after file is sent

Comment: @IłyaBursov Hy... Thanks, but any ideas how? I should be generating the hash from the same loop as I read and encrypt? Do u mean as I read a block of bytes I should generate a hash for that block? If so, if I read many blocks and encrypt it would  mean I'd have generated many hash right?

Comment: yes, generate hash in the same loop - pick any hashing algorithm and implement it